# Need a Java method that creates buttons

Tags: java, swing, parsing, button, arguments

I'm trying to create a method `myMethod` in JAVA that can fill a user defined jPanel with buttons according to the panels size. It works if I change "Object j" to "jFrameScreen j" , remove Component p and change variable p to j. jPanel2 in `myMethod`.
But that's not what I want, I want the user to be able to determine what jFrame and jPanel the buttons will be created on when calling `myMethod`.

When I run the code as shown here it gives me these errors:

```
p.add(btn[b]);  //JButton cannot be converted to PopupMenu
j.setVisible(true); //Cannot find symbol, method setVisible(boolean)
```

My work is as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        jFrameScreen j = new jFrameScreen();
        myMethod(j, j.jPanel2, 10, 10, 600, 400);
    }
    public static void myMethod(Object j, Component p, int col, int row, int myWidth, int myHeight) {
        int bWidth = myWidth / col;
        int bHeight = myHeight / row;
        int numberOfButtons = (myWidth / bWidth) * (myHeight / bHeight);
        JButton btn[] = new JButton[numberOfButtons];
        for (int k = 0, x = 0, b = 0; k < myWidth / bWidth; k++, x += bWidth) {
            for (int i = 0, y = 0; i < myHeight / bHeight; i++, y += bHeight, b++) {
                btn[b] = new JButton();
                btn[b].setBounds(2 + x, 3 + y, bWidth, bHeight);
                btn[b].setText(Integer.toString(b));
                btn[b].setVisible(true);
                p.add(btn[b]);  //JButton cannot be converted to PopupMenu
            }
        } 

        p.setVisible(true);  
        j.setVisible(true);  //Cannot find symbol, method setVisible(boolean)
     }
}
```

Comment: Hint: j and p are terrible variable names. Use names that communicate meaning to human readers!

Comment: @GhostCat  Hi :) Totally right. I updated with it.

Comment: Hi @user3888775 your code is slightly unreadable you should follow the java naming convention for the helper's here to understand your code http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable declared with the `Object` type doesn't have a `setVisible()` method.

And `Component.add()` accepts only instances of the `PopupMenu` class :

```
 public void add(PopupMenu popup) {
```

> But that's not what I want, I want the user to be able to determine
>   what jFrame and jPanel the buttons will be created on when calling
>   "myMethod".

You try to provide a generic method but you don't rely on suitable base classes according to your requirements.
`Object` and `Component` are too generic to represent respectively a `JFrame` and  a `JPanel`.

If these two parameters have to represent instances of these types, just use them : replace `Object j`  by `JFrame j` and   `Component p` by `JPanel p`.

Besides, their naming is really not good. `frame` and `panel` are better :

```
public static void myMethod(JFrame frame, JPanel panel, int col, int row, int myWidth, int myHeight) {
```

Comment: Thanks davidxxx, changing to JFrame and JPanel worked!

Comment: If I want to pass a reference to another method in the myMethod arguments. What should I do ?

Comment: It depends on the method parameters and return types.

Comment: I was thinking of an onclick event that calls a method that the user has pasted as an argument in myMethod

Comment: btn[b].addActionListener(e -> {
                    someUserDefinedMethod();
                
                });

Comment: If you have no argument and return in the method, you could provide a `Runnable` parameter to accept the method or maybe better, create your own functional interface : `@FunctionalInterface
interface MyTask {
  void doTask();
}`